# SQL Server - time stamp declaration

Tags: sql-server

I have to create a table. I have 10-15 columns which need to be declared as time stamps in SQL Server, but I get an error that SQL will allow only one timestamp per table. Could you please let me know how do I declare all these 10-15 columns as time stamps in one table creation.

Rgds.,
Sajan.

Comment: The `TIMESTAMP` datatype in SQL Server has ***absolutely nothing*** to do with a regular date & time. Other than the ISO Standard SQL, it is **NOT** a date and time - it's a **binary, system-operated** counter, really - and it's now more properly called `ROWVERSION`, and in fact you can only have ***one*** per table. For date&time, use `DATE`, or `DATETIME2(n)` (if you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DATETIME? As far as I know, perhaps SQL server doesn't have TIMESTAMP. If really needed, use VARCHAR to store the values, but that'd be a very cheap approach!